# sql server grouping results

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

this query returns the list below it, however the ids occur multiple times, can i group the ids and add up all the plays so i just get a list unique ids with the total number of plays next to it. is this possible in sql?

```
SELECT [fkPlayerId],[plays]
FROM [dPlaysPerDay]
INNER JOIN dWinners
ON [dPlaysPerDay].[fkPlayerId]=dWinners.[pkWinnerId]

53693   1
53695   1
53696   1
53693   1
53692   2
53698   2
53697   1
53699   2
53698   3
53693   6
53699   2
53693   2
53700   2
53698   1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When using `GROUP BY`, all data items in the `SELECT`, must either be included in the `GROUP BY` or placed in an [Aggregate Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173454.aspx).

Therefore, `fkPlayerId` should be grouped by, and `plays` used with the [`SUM()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187810%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) function

```
SELECT [fkPlayerId], SUM([plays])
FROM [dPlaysPerDay]
INNER JOIN dWinners ON [dPlaysPerDay].[fkPlayerId]=dWinners.[pkWinnerId]
GROUP BY fkPlayerId
```

To `ORDER BY` the aggregate function, give the data item an alias, and Order by this:

```
SELECT [fkPlayerId], SUM([plays]) as TotalPlays
FROM [dPlaysPerDay]
INNER JOIN dWinners ON [dPlaysPerDay].[fkPlayerId]=dWinners.[pkWinnerId]
GROUP BY fkPlayerId
ORDER BY TotalPlays
```

Comment: cool thanks curt! can i order by that second coumn? i know you can use order by [column name] but here we get a coulmn with no name?